# Why do I get these 404-Errors?

Tags: security, http-status-code-404

I have a website and I check the 404 errors I get quite often. For most of them, I have a quite good explanation why I get them. But some appear quite often, although I am sure I have never posted a link like this.

Here is a list of some strange 404 errors:

- `js/Swiff.CallBacks`
- `//phpscheduleit/` or `//sched/` or `//scheduler/`
- `/%b0z2%b5%b5a`
- `js/+this.options.encoding:`
- `js/).match(/\d+/g);return{version:parseInt(a[0]||0+`
- `js/application/json`
- `js/text/xml`
- `js/;this.headers.set(`

I jused mootools for my JavaScript part, now I use Google Closure. Is this an hacking attempt? How could this attempt be successfull?

Should I change anything because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `//phpscheduleit/` is checking for software which has a [vulnerability](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CAN-2008-6132).
- `/%b0z2%b5%b5a` is a name that one might use to install a malicious script to keep it obscure, but since a Google search doesn't turn up anything it's not a standard name.
  (It might also be testing for a [Unicode decoding vulnerability](http://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/80.html), but it would make more sense for it to check a particular vulnerable URL involving `%c0%af` directly.)
- `js/;this.headers.set(` and the like look like bits of Javascript code that a web crawler might pick out as possible URLs. Do these string appear on your website? Not necessarily malicous, but I don't think there's a legitimate reason to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Are they coming from any specific IP address or range?  You could try blocking that, or adding logic to automatically block IPs when they attempt to access any of the suspicious "strange" URLs that don't exist.

It looks like this is from an automated tool to scan for known vulnerabilities in various Javascript libraries.  Common ones are [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf), and [privilege escalation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation).

On a hunch, I'm going to say it's a spam bot.

Comment: Here are some IPs: 85.10.211.218, 89.123.59.241, 92.43.110.80. Do you know any software for detecting spambots and denying access? As these files don't exist and they don't have any arguments, I don't think it's one of those attacs you mentioned. At least not in a way that I know.

Comment: There may be some libraries out there, but it wouldn't be difficult to collect 404 log items that look suspicious, put the URLs in a list, and automatically blacklist any IP that requests something on the list.